# Golang generics - cannot use a type in place of the same type while passing a function pointer

Tags: go, generics, function-pointers

I am new to golang and I am working on the following struct:

```golang
type Flag[T any] struct {
    defaultValue interface{}
}
```

Where `T` can be `int` or `bool`

I have defined the following function:

```golang
func (f Flag[T]) GetVariation(val interface{}, getFunc func(v T) T ) T {
    inputVal := f.defaultValue.(T)

    return getFunc(inputVal)
}
```

When I try to use the above function for various data types, like bool by using something like:

```golang
func (f Flag[bool]) GetBoolVariation(val bool) bool {
    return f.GetVariation(val, someFunc)
}

func someFunc(v bool) bool {
    return true
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
cannot use someFunc (value of type func(v bool)  bool) as func(v bool) bool value in argument to f.GetVariation
```

The message is very confusing because it says that I cannot use "X" as "X". Could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, hard to gauge your larger use case here, but generics may not be the best fit here is you are going to do runtime type inspection (e.g. `f.defaultValue.(T)`).

Secondly, it appears you are using `go 1.20`, which does indeed yield a confusing error:

https://go.dev/play/p/IpykGv6yxZt?v=goprev

```
cannot use someFunc (value of type func(v bool) bool) as func(v bool) bool value in argument to f.GetVariation
```

Using the latest playground version (`go 1.21` as of this writing) gives a more detailed compilation error:

https://go.dev/play/p/IpykGv6yxZt

```
./prog.go:14:29: cannot use someFunc (value of type func(v bool) bool) as func(v bool /* with bool declared at ./prog.go:13:14 */) bool /* with bool declared at ./prog.go:13:14 */ value in argument to f.GetVariation
```

indicating the location of where the type `bool` is specified (`./prog.go:13:14`) stems from the type constraint.

So, just because this type constraint `bool` matches the non-generic function signature:

```
func someFunc(v bool) bool {
    return true
}
```

does not mean it is an exact compilation match.

You can "solve" the compilation error with [this contrived example](https://go.dev/play/p/xV0Gl07Dsbz):

```
func someFuncFix[T any](v T) T {
    return v
}

func (f Flag[bool]) GetBoolVariation(val bool) bool {
    return f.GetVariation(val, someFuncFix[bool])

    // FYI: `return f.GetVariation(val, someFuncFix)` also works as the bool constraint could be inferred
}
```

But again, I think generics may not be the best solution for your particular use-case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, generics is indeed an overkill here. Since i am new to the language i was exploring all the ways i could do this - and stumbled upon this cryptic error.

Comment: Couldn't have guessed that changing the version would give more info of the error.